# Reference request for Miller-Morita-Mumford classes.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I am looking for a reference to learn about Miller-Morita-Mumford classes. I have experience in characteristic classes of vector bundles e.g. Stiefel-Whitney classes, Chern classes, Pontryagin classes, and Euler classes. I can't seem to find any sources which are not highly specialized research articles. Any recommendations?

Comment: Algebraic independence of generalized MMM–classes by Johannes Ebert looks very good to me with the primary result being that almost all MMM classes are different. I don't think the theory of these is really known to the extent that characteristic classes of bundles is.

Comment: There is also this very interesting paper Characteristic classes for families of bundles by Alexander Berglund that was put on the arxiv today. It looks to me like it studies rational MMM classes by constructing certain rational models. Both of these papers have a ton of good results.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into those papers.